# Why is address containing & is all printed as &amp?

Tags: php, apache2

I have just done the website migration from the old server to the new server. The new server has PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.5, and apache2 and etc.

The old site was working perfectly fine, and the new site in the new server works fine except all the urls containing & prints out as `&amp;`

For example, below line is a snippet of the source code, which should actually print the css file. However, since & has been changed to `&amp;` , css file does not get called, and site works without the cs file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="script.php?l=329ef537b34ea622036c008096902d53&amp;t=.css" type="text/css" charset="UTF-8" media="all">
```

which should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="script.php?l=329ef537b34ea622036c008096902d53&t=.css" type="text/css" charset="UTF-8" media="all">
```

and also, below example

```
<a href="blog/?mid=lacta&amp;act=display">PROFILE</a></li>
```

should be

```
<a href="blog/?mid=lacta&act=display">PROFILE</a></li>
```

What do you think is the reason for causing this?
Files has not changed and mysql data has not changed either. I moved everything from old server to new server. What setting in new server do I have to change to correctly print & ?

-----------Updated

For the current server, I am using Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu 10.04) and PHP
php.ini settings are all default, and Yes I am using rewrite module...

Old server was using Apache/1.3.36 and PHP 5.1.4..

Domain name, .htaccess files, all other files are same.

Comment: Please show us the PHP code producing the HTML.

Comment: Are you using any `mod_rewrite` or any other apache modules? Also, what OS and webserver version does the old server run? What is the `arg_separator.input` value in your php.ini and how do your PHP scripts access the query params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URIs should contain ampersands as entity encoded values. It's perfectly correct this way.

See [Special Characters in URI attribute values](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2)

Comment: Hey, My old website is printing & as it is. Do you think it may be a problem relating to character encoding??

Comment: @user, [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: @user what @Charles said. Whatever is causing your script to malfunction, it's not the encoded ampersands in your HTML. Without knowing much more details about your setup, I can only blindly guess (which I wont), so please update your question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

have a look in your php.ini for this
arg_separator.output
and change it accordingly, it could be causing the problem